# How do I rename a java type? (String to string)

Tags: java, string, types, reference, rename

I'm really used to using "string" instead of "String" in C#. I was wondering what I can do to be able to do this in Java.

I'm using Eclipse's Java EE IDE if that matters.

Comment: this is a terrible idea.

Comment: This is not recommended.

Comment: I would wager that it's not possible (short of hacking the IDE/compiler).  And even it were, it's a really silly idea.

Comment: It guarantees that no one else will ever want to work on your code.  Would you have written "String" in C#?  If not, why change just for Java?   Write in the idiom the language demands or go back to C#.

Comment: Just write String. Or you could write a pre-processor and run all your source code through that. Call it Java#. You could change more of the language. In fact, you could write a compiler and change the entire language, and call it Scala, or Clojure, or Groovy. If you want to target the JVM and you don't want to write Java, there are other languages that run on the JVM. But if you want to write in Java, then write in Java.

Comment: excellent trollbait Maxwell -- Very Funny

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - you'd have to hack parts of the core JVM and SE class libraries as well ...

Answer (score 5):

> How do I rename a Java type? (`String` to `string`)

This is not possible:

- Java does not allow you to rename or alias types.  Each (class) type has one and only one FQN (i.e. fully qualified name).  Any type with a different FQN is a different type.
- The `String` type is declared as `final` so you couldn't even create a convenience subclass.  (And even if it did, it wouldn't help because you can't change the rest of the system libraries to use your class.)
- Changing system libraries while theoretically possible is a REALLY, REALLY BAD IDEA, because it would break compatibility with everything under the sun, starting with your Java toolchain and IDE.
- Changing the name of `String` would be particularly difficult because of the cross-dependencies between this class, generated code and the JVM internals.  In particular, there are some really scary relationships between this class and the JVM bootstrap process.
- And even if it was technically feasible to do this, it would STILL be a bad idea ... from the perspective of code maintainability.  Think of the next guy who would have to read and modify your mongrel "Java looking like C#" codebase.

> I'm really used to using "string" instead of "String" in C#.

You just need to learn to use `String` ... like the millions of other C# programmers who have learned Java.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Just use String. You'll get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

`String` is a <strike>wrapper</strike> proper first-class Class in Java, and there's no primitive data-type of string in java, unlike in C#.

Coding conventions in Java states that classes need to start with an uppercase letter. So, no you can't rename it.

Comment: This is incorrect.  String is a proper first-class Class in Java: it is not a "wrapper" for anything.  Indeed, in modern JVMs, the `String` class is implemented completely in Java ... no native code.

Comment: Thanks for the save there. I almost forgot wrapper classes are made for primitive data-types like `int` -> `Integer`.

Comment: The string class isn't primitive in C#, either, but it's got a name that indicates that's it's a basic type, which is nice. Still, write C# when you're writing C#, and Java when you're writing Java. Horses for courses.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it were not a bad idea, I don't think this is possible. There are no typedefs in java, so you cannot alias a class. In addition String is a final class and thus cannot be extended -- meaning you can't extend String and call it string.

Answer (score 0):

For lulz only

```
public final class string {
    private final String string;
    public string(String string){
        this.string = string;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return string;
    }

    //usage
    public static void main(String args[]){
       string myString = new string("Hello World");
       System.out.println(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to explain the joke ... i.e. why this class is (almost) no use to the OP.

Comment: I think he gets the point with the 7 downvotes

Comment: I'm not talking about explaining for the OP.  I'm talking about explaining for other people ...